# Java Dynamic Proxy - How reference concrete class

Tags: java, dynamic, proxy

I have a question relating to dynamic proxies in java.

Suppose I have an interface called `Foo` with a method `execute` and class `FooImpl implements Foo`.

When I create a proxy for `Foo` and I have something like:

```
Foo f = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
                                     new Class[] { Foo.class },
                                     handler);
```

Suppose my invocation handler looks like:

```
public class FooHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If my invocation code looks something like

```
Foo proxyFoo = (Foo) Proxy.newInstance(Foo.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                                       new Class[] { Foo.class },
                                       new FooHandler());
proxyFoo.execute();
```

If the proxy can intercept the aforementioned call `execute` from the `Foo` interface, where does the `FooImpl` come in to play? Maybe I am looking at dynamic proxies in the wrong way. What I want is to be able to catch the `execute` call from a concrete implementation of `Foo`, such as `FooImpl`. Can this be done?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to intercept methods using dynamic proxies are by:

```
public class FooHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object realObject;

    public FooHandler (Object real) {
        realObject=real;
    }


    public Object invoke(Object target, Method method, Object[] arguments) throws Throwable {
        if ("execute".equals(method.getName()) {
            // intercept method named "execute"
        }

        // invoke the original methods
        return method.invoke(realObject, arguments);
    }
}
```

Invoke the proxy by:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] {Foo.class}, 
            new FooHandler(new FooImpl()));
```

Comment: Thanks guys. So an invocation of my code would look like: Foo f = new FooImpl(); FooHandler fh = new FooHandler(f); correct?

Comment: @Johan: I'm sure you didn't mean to write `new Foo()` there, as first of all Foo is an interface. I think that should be `new FooHandler(new FooImpl())`.

Comment: Guys, just one last thing - Why does the 'Foo.class.getClassLoader()' need to be passed in as an argument to the newProxyInstance method? What exactly does that do? Thanks

Comment: @Joeblackdev, In environments when using e.g., multiple jar-files they will each provide their own classloader and it might be desirable to select which to use.

Comment: @Joeblackdev: A class is only "equal to itself" in the same class loader. If `Foo` is loaded in some other CL it will be a different class. So you want to make sure that the returned `Foo` does not come from some other class loader, or otherwise you'll get a `ClassCastException`. The Proxy doesn't want to rely on the context classloader of the current thread as that's not guaranteed to be the one you expect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delegate to some Foo implementation like FooImpl, just make your InvocationHandler a wrapper of an other Foo instance (passed to the constructor) and then send a FooImpl instance as the delegate. Then, inside the `handler.invoke()` method, call method.invoke(delegate, args).