# Java, can I apply an arbitrary interface to an existing class?

Tags: java, interface

If two classes have some methods of exact same signature, but those methods are not inherited, is there any way to define an interface with the common methods and point both instances of the two classes using the same interface?

For example, suppose a class `Cat` has `boolean isAlive()` and another class `Dog` has `boolean isAlive()` but `Cat` and `Dog` has no common ancestor other than `Object` and `boolean isAlive()` is not an inherited method. I cannot modify `Cat` or `Dog` because they were written by others. Can I arbitrarily create an interface like that and use it to point a Cat or a Dog?

```
interface lovable
{
    boolean isAlive();
}

void main()
{
    lovable thing = new Cat(); <-- any syntax to achieve this?
    love(thing);
}

void love(lovable thing)
{
    if (thing.isAlive())
        System.out.println("Aww.");
    else
        System.out.println("Eww.");
}
```

Comment: `class Cat implements lovable`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196941/can-you-force-a-java-object-into-implementing-an-interface-at-runtime

Comment: @QBrute to cite the OP: "I cannot modify Cat or Dog because they were written by others." so that doesn't seem possible/feasible.

Comment: `lovable thing = (new Cat())::isAlive;`

Comment: That question is almost exactly the same as mine. I did search StackOverflow before posting, I wonder why I could not find it. As that person said, I am already using so-called adapter, and I just wondered if there was easier and faster way.

Comment: `lovable thing = (new Cat())::isAlive` worked for this case. But it does not seem to work if the interface has more than one method.

Comment: If you would like to access only getters and setters (bean style), you can use `Commons BeanUtils`. In this way you should not care about class of objects. Let me know, if you need example.

Comment: No... I need more than getters and setters. Actually the two classes are some kind of file reader classes. They both have methods like read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length), but are not inherited from a common parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create Proxy object as was mentioned in [Can you force a java object into implementing an interface at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196941/can-you-force-a-java-object-into-implementing-an-interface-at-runtime) :

```
public interface Loveable {
    boolean isAlive();
}

public static class Cat {
    boolean isAlive() {
        return true;
    }
}

public static class Dog {
    boolean isAlive() {
        return false;
    }
}

public static <T> T getWrapper(final Object obj, final Class<T> intface) {
    InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            return obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes()).invoke(obj, args);
        }
    };
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(obj.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{intface}, invocationHandler);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getWrapper(new Cat(), Loveable.class).isAlive());
    System.out.println(getWrapper(new Dog(), Loveable.class).isAlive());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example. Though it may be more complicated than I thought, it certainly showed me an interesting possibility Java is capable of.

Comment: Can we generalise `Loveable` in getWrapper() so that we can reuse it for other interfaces?

Answer (score 5):

If you create it by yourself:

```
public interface Lovable{
    boolean isAlive();
}

public class LovableCat extends Cat implements Lovable{

}
```

---

```
public static void main() {
    Lovable thing = new LovableCat();
    love(thing);
}
```

If returned from somewhere else:

```
public interface Lovable{
    boolean isAlive();
}

public class LovableCat implements Lovable{

    private Cat cat;

    public LovableCat(Cat cat){
       this.cat = cat;
    }

    public boolean isAlive(){
       return cat.isAlive();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main() {
    Lovable thing = new LovableCat(cat);
    love(thing);
}
```

Comment: Curious: Why not `public class LovableCat extends Cat implements Lovable` ?

Comment: Good idea. But anyways you'll need to implement `isLovable();`

Comment: @bradimus I updated my answer, but if you want, you can post as yours, and I'll delete mine )

Comment: No worries. I edited your answer to implement the interface.

Comment: By the way, it will be better to not implement interface. In this case value will be return from parent class method. From `Cat`.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot that the OP was extracting the interface from existing functionality.

Comment: This assumes that I created the instance of `Cat` myself. (In my question I did use `new Cat()`, but it was just to make the example simple.) But `Cat` is returned from a method which was written by others, so I must wrap it, because I cannot typecast `Cat` to `LovableCat`. I was already doing this and wondered if there was an easier way.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun with generic approach we even can improve second variant. For cases, when yor `Cat` and `Dog` have many other methods.

Comment: So, if we use generic, we do not need to create separate `LovableCat` and `LovableDog`, but only one class? Could you modify `LovableCat` using generic, then? I guess that could be more helpful.

Comment: No, if we'll use generic, we'll need `LovableCat` and `LovableDog` anyway. But you can implement method to get native object `Cat` or `Dog` from wrapper class to use other methods. But seems, in your case, it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't  because your types (Cat, Dog) have to implement your interface. How ever you have 2 solutions if this classes from some lib. The first to use wrapper as was mentioned and the second to use reflection. I suppose  the lib  www.eclipse.org/aspectj could help you to implement this with minimal afforts.